# Usage of versine, coversine, haversine, exsecant

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I found trigonometric functions like versine, vercosine, haversine, exsecant, etc. But they are very simply related to the six basic trig functions. Like
$$\mathrm{versin}{(\theta)}=1-\cos{(\theta)}$$
$$\mathrm{coversin}{(\theta)}=1-\sin{(\theta)}$$
$$\mathrm{haversin}{(\theta)}=\frac{1-\cos{(\theta)}}{2}$$
$$\mathrm{exsec}{(\theta)}=\sec{(\theta)}-1$$
Haversine is literally just half of versine. Why and how are these functions needed over the six basic trig functions?

Comment: I think it's just history: at some point some author felt his problem was best thought of using $\mathrm{versin}$ or whatever. And your six "basic" trig functions (presumably $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, $\mathrm{cotan}$, $\sec$ and $\mathrm{cosec}$) can all be defined in terms of $\sin$, so why do you feel the need for the other five?

Comment: @RobArthan To be pedantic, a given $\sin$ allows two different $\cos$. So you need two. But your point stands.

Comment: Specialized investigations often spawn specialized notations. Eg, John Conway's ["triangle notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_triangle_notation) $S_A:=\frac12(-a^2+b^2+c^2)$, which is "just" a re-writing of the Law of Cosines formula $bc\cos A$, provides *cleaner* forms of relations often enough to become somewhat popular. In some cases, type-setting expediency —esp. in older publications— may have prompted authors to define an "inline" name to represent an expression involving fractions or exponents (eg, $\operatorname{haversin}\theta$ instead of $\sin^2\frac12\theta$).

Comment: @spatial: thank you for the correction: I confess my sin: I should have said "up to sign the trig functions can be all defined in terms of $\sin$", would you have signed up to that $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @Blue: that's a very good point. Going back to the 17th and 18th century, you often see $xx$ rather than $x^2$, because the printer would have charged more for typesetting a superscript $2$ than a second $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact only $\sin$ and $\cos$ are enough. These are useful because of double/half angle relations, specifically $\mathrm{haversine}(\theta)  = \sin^2(\theta/2) $.

Some of these have historical roots.
For example, haversine was important because of its use in global navigation, see [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).